# 'li' mouseover event being prevented by child 'a' element display block

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to display a sub-navigation `<ul>` tag on it's parent `<li>`'s `mouseover` event.  The problem is that the `a` element is set to `display:block`, so the `li`'s `hover` event is never fired.

It works using jQuery, but I can't get it to work with plain javascript.  I'm applying the listener to the header element, and using the `.matchesSelector` method to determine if the event target matches `.nav > li;`

Comment: Code is worth a thousand words.

Answer (score 0):

Without the code, one has to *guess*, but my guess is that you're using `mouseover` and `mouseout` to determine hovering. The `mouseout` event *bubbles*, so you'll receive `mouseout` from the descendant elements of the `li`, and mistakenly (again I'm guessing here) think the cursor has left the `li` rather than it having left one of the descendant elements of the `li`. Similarly, when the cursor moves from the `li` itself into a descendant element, the `li` triggers a `mouseout`. It works in jQuery (using `hover`, presumably?) because jQuery doesn't use `mouseover` and `mouseout`, it uses `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, which are more suited to this scenario. (And it emulates them on browsers that don't have them natively; they were originally IE-only.)

So if you're using jQuery, obviously, just use `hover`. If you're not and you're either not using a library, or using one that doesn't emulate `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` for you, you need to check which element the `mouseout` operation is coming from and ignore it unless it's the `li` itself.

If the sub-navigation `ul` won't cover the `li` that reveals it, you might consider a CSS-only solution. For instance, with the structure:

```
<ul class="mainnav"><!-- Main nav -->
  <li><!-- Nav item 1 -->
    Nav Text 1
    <ul><!-- Menu for nav item 1 -->
    ...
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><!-- Nav item 2 -->
    Nav Text 2
    <ul><!-- Menu for nav item 2 -->
    ...
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This CSS will do it (you'd want more than this, for positioning, but this will do the show/hide part):

```
ul.mainnav > li > ul {
  display: none;
}
ul.mainnav > li:hover > ul {
  display: none;
}
```

That won't work on IE6; it works as of IE7 and higher (if you're in standards mode).

Answer (score 0):

Why not define event handlers for all the child elements and then do a

```
event.cancelBubble = true; //IE
event.stopPropagation(); //FF, etc
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The `li` *itself* fires a `mouseout` when the cursor moves from the `li` to a child element of it. Tracking hover using `mouseover` and `mouseout` is more complicated than just canceling the events from descendants.